# How to make SVG works on mobile?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple SVG animation.

HTML:

```
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg>
```

CSS:

```
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzb71rw6/)

The problem with this SVG is, it only works on desktop browsers. When I test it out on mobile (latest Chrome and Safari on iOS8) and native Android Lollipop browser, it's not showing.

I already try to add `<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN” “http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd”>` but it's still didn't work.

What should I do to make this SVG works on both desktop and mobile?

Comment: That doesn't even work on a desktop for me (in chrome or opera)

Comment: works fine on Chrome here (v 44.0.2403.155)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SVGs on mobile browsers, SVG SMIL animation (aka the `<animate>` element) seems much [better supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) than css animation, which looks like below.

```
<animate xlink:href="#checkmark__check" 
         attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
         from="48" 
         to="0"
         dur="3s" 
         fill="freeze">
```

Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/rvbssfmd/3/

Here's a tutorial from CSS Tricks about SMIL animation: https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

Comment: Ok, but why the checkmark animation is slower and the circle background is black (its original color is green)?

Comment: Nvm, just found the way to change the duration & the color. https://jsfiddle.net/rvbssfmd/5/

Comment: It's only a simplified example :)